# Jquery datepicker get currently active date range

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I wonder how could I get the active date range from datepicker object in case I use several months view. You can see the example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y58p7168/).
The desired output is January 31 and February 3.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Considered using Bootstrap date range picker? Works pretty well. http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Well, it's impossible in this project. I need to get solution for Datepicker as for now :)

Comment: the issue is, Datepicker returns a date, rather than a range of dates. You're really going to either need to use a dateRangePicker, as @JonathanHamel suggested Bootstrap's or something like http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/ for jQueryUI, or hack the heck out of the datePicker to create your own dateRangePicker.

Comment: I could suggest using a solution like this one ? http://jsfiddle.net/548cLod4/1/ Keep a reference to both dates and highlight them before rendering the calendar.